# Load data into a hdb instance in kdb

Tags: kdb

how to load data from folder /tmp/HDB/ into a hdb instance on port 2020

I have data extracts into the folder /tmp/HDB/ and want to upload the data to the hdb instance of port 2020 in kx refinery.

I tried the below
q -p 2020

```
q) assetA: `:2020:assetA  


assetATable: `:2020:assetA:tableName
folderPathA: "/tmp/HDB/"

.u.comm[`:2020:assetA]
select from assetATable where date = 2023.09.01
```

But this gives error at .u.comm[`:2020:assetA]

Answer (score 2):

With a plain `q` process, loading simply means using the `\l` command on the directory - in this case

```
\l /tmp/HDB
```

However you seem to be using a customized environment. Can you check that `.u.comm` is defined in the local process, and if not, do whatever is needed to make it available? Also you just said it "gives an error" but not what the actual error message is, which could be valuable information on how to debug it.